# How to trigger deeplinks?

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-deep-link

In my app I have enabled deeplinks like:

```
<activity android:name="com.example.android.DeepLinkActivity">
    <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
        <data android:host="www.bartsimposon.net" android:scheme="https"/>
        <data android:pathPattern="/kwitchiboo/.*\\.html"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

I was expecting when I enter in my smartphones browser

> https://www.bartsimpson.net\kwitchiboo\something.html

to trigger my `DeepLinkActivity` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to click this link, not enter manually in address field/omnibox in some browser. navigate to this site/topic on your mobile and try to click in here:

https://www.bartsimpson.net/kwitchiboo/something.html

after your app installation and first this-kind link click system will ask you in which app you want to open URL, browser or your app. there will be also "always" and "only once" options